# Cordova diagnostic plugin switchToLocationSettings()

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I work on a cordova jquery mobile project.

I would like to know if it is possible to have a callback after triggered the switchToLocationSettings() function.

i would like to know if the user have enabled GPS on his device.

i use it like this:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
```

but i would like something like this:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings(Success,Error);
```

is it possible?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Nop, I Just exit user from the app.

Comment: I think exit from app is not good solution for this, something else should be find out.

Answer (score 1):

According to `Java Code`, there is no `callback method` for this function. Check Below -

```
    /**
 * Requests that the user enable the location in device settings.
 */
public void switchToLocationSettings() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Switch to Location Settings");
    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    ctx.startActivity(settingsIntent);
}
```

That's why you are not able to pass any extra `callback function` in this `method`. You have to write your own `code`.